# frameset not picking up css

Tags: asp.net, css

Is it normal behavior for the frame src page not to apply the css referenced in the container page?

For example the external style sheet has an id #divbody that sets the color of the text. Header.aspx had the div id called divbody.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>    
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<frameset rows="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="Header.aspx" />
  <frame src="Body.aspx" />
  <frame src="Footer.aspx" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Frames are like windows: they are distinct universes with their own css styles and everything else.

Comment: You'll need to include the stylesheet in each frame document as well.

Comment: I'd just add one more thing - DO NOT USE frames unless absolutely necessary. There are numerous articles on the internet about it, so maybe you should read them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Frame is a separate document. Each document needs to contain its OWN stylesheet. It cannot be inherited from the parent window.